# Pytorch: Find the indexes in a second 2D tensor, of the matching elements of a first 2D tensor in a vectorized way

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a graph matching situation where I have old indexes and new indexes. The indexes tensors are tuples (i,j) with different sizes.

Let's say the new tuples are `a` and the old tuples are `b`:

```py
a = torch.LongTensor([[0,1], [0,2], [1,3], [2,4], [3,5]])
b = torch.LongTensor([[1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [3,5]])
```

What I need is a mask to know what new tuples are already in the old tuples array, and at the same time, the indexes of the old array that correspond to the new tuples. A working code is the following one:

```py
existing_edges_mask = torch.zeros(a.shape[0]).long()
corresponding_old_idx = []
for idx, edge_idx in enumerate(a):
    if edge_idx in b:
        try:
            corresponding_old_idx.append(
                ((b == edge_idx).sum(
                    dim=1) == 2).nonzero().item()
            )
            existing_edges_mask[idx] = True
        except ValueError:
            continue

>>> print(existing_edges_mask)
tensor([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
>>> print(corresponding_old_idx)
[1, 3]
```

The code is painfully slow for large arrays of tuples, any idea on how to optimize this solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does `print(corresponding_old_idx)` print just `[1, 3]` instead of `[[1, 3], [3, 5]]` since `[3, 5]` is also in both old and new arrays?

Comment: Are the indices in both tensors guaranteed to be unique and sorted as in the included example?

Comment: `print(corresponding_old_idx)`prints `[1,3]` because these are the indexes of the corresponding tuples in the old array, as the pair `[1,3]` is indexed in the `1` position in the old array, and the tuple `[3,5]` is indexed in the `3`position in the old array

Comment: All the indices are unique in each array and they are ordered by the first entry